# Custom view in Object Library and IB compatible in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I have a control in one of my storyboard that I copy in a lot of screen and even projects. It's just native controls with stack view, scroll views, labels, etc placed with auto-layout already wired together.

Is there a way to add this into the Object Library in Xcode so I can just drag it from there onto my storyboard and still see all the native controls? I want to be able to drag and drop other controls into the stack view and even modify it from there within IB.

I do not want to do this programatically because I want to continue using Interface Builder for my custom control.

Answer (score 1):

> s there a way to add this into the Object Library in Xcode so I can just drag it from there onto my storyboard and still see all the native controls?

No. The usual strategy is to keep it in a xib file (so you are using Interface Builder to construct the view complex) and load the nib programatically to get at the view and put it in the interface at runtime.  To some extent you can automate that programmatic process by means of a view subclass that loads its  own content from the nib.

Or, if this view has different manifestations in different contexts, you might just have to use copy and paste of some template version (presumably you’re already doing that).